# How to use custom created Entity in Azure Logic app 365 connector for operations

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I have created a new Entity in Dynamics 365 for Operations and I am trying to populate it using the Azure Logic App 365 for operations connector.

The logic app connector connects to the D365o instance and lists a large number of entities, but not the custom one I created. I have verified I am connected to the right instance by inserting data into one of the listed Entities and verifying the data.

I have looked at the properties on the Entity I created and nothing really stands out, public was set to yes by default and I have not touched anything else. Any ideas on what I could be missing in order to expose my custom Entity to the logic app connector?

Thank you

Comment: Is your entity public? Can you use access the OData service for your entity? It's what logic apps depend on.

Answer (score 0):

"*I have looked at the properties on the Entity I created and nothing really stands out, public was set to yes by default and I have not touched anything else.*"

Does it mean that you left `PublicCollectionName` and `PublicEntityName` empty? Can you fill them in, recompile, refresh data entity list and try accessing your data entity again, using its `PublicCollectionName`?